# structuring classes for a tic-tac-toe(c++)

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have been learning c++ with 'C++ Programming for
the Absolute Beginner' which have been very useful, whoever when it comes to OOP and splitting the classes into different files it doesn't explain it very well.

This is the code I have, I didn't put everything here, just the problematic stuff. The weird thing is that if I exclude Juego.h and Juego.cpp from the project it lets me build it, but if I include it I get the following errors:

```
jugador.h(8): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'c_o'
jugador.h(8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
jugador.h(9): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'casilla'
juego.cpp(15): error C2039: 'c_o' : is not a member of 'Jugador'    
jugador.h(5) : see declaration of 'Jugador'
```

Because it only happens with Juego.h in the code I think the problem is that  I didn't structure well the header files. I have been able to solve many of the problems searching on google but I can't fix those, I even get syntax errors.

```
//Jugador.h
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Jugador
{
public:
    string p_name;
//casilla is X,O or blankspace, done using enum in Tablero.h( it have to be in a cpp file)
    casilla c_o;
Player(string name, casilla marca);
void turno(Tablero* tabla);
};


//Jugador.cpp
#include "Jugador.h"
#inlcude "Tablero.h"
#include <string>

using std::string;

Jugador::Jugador(string nombre,casilla marca): p_name(nombre), c_o(marca) {} 

void Jugador::turno(Tablero* tabla)
{

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int fil;
int col;
do
{
    cout << p_name.c_str() <<" en que fila quieres jugar(1-2-3)?\n";
    cin >> fil;
    cout<<p_name.c_str()  <<" en que columna quieres jugar(1-2-3)?\n";
    cin >> col;
}while(tabla->tab[fil-1][col-1]==vacia);
tabla->tab[fil-1][col-1]=c_o;
}


//Juego.h
class Jugador;
class Tablero;

class Juego
{
public:
Juego(void);
bool ganador(Jugador* player, Tablero* tabla);
bool fin(Tablero* tabla);
};


//Juego.cpp
#include "Juego.h"
#include "Jugador.h"
#include "Tablero.h"

Juego::Juego() {}

bool Juego::ganador(Jugador* player, Tablero* tabla)
{
using std::cout;
using std::cin;


casilla marca_jug = player->c_o;
bool winner = false;

    //...
// if-else structure which set winner to true if the conditons to win are achived       

if (winner)
    cout<<player->p_name.c_str()<<" ha ganado!!!!\n";

return winner;
}

//if there isnt any blank square, ends the game
bool Juego::fin(Tablero* tabla)
{
bool fin_juego=false;

for(int fil=0; fil<3; fil++)
{
    for(int col=0; col<3; col++)
    {
        if(tabla->tab[fil][col]==vacia)
            fin_juego=true;
    }
}

return fin_juego;
}
```

As I said it isn't the whole code, I wasnt to have more things that needed just to make everything clearer I'm gonna add tablero.h

Here is were casilla is defined. Casilla is a 2D array:

```
//Tablero.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum casilla {vacia,X,O};

class Tablero
{
public:
casilla tab[3][3];
Tablero(void);
void draw(void);
};


//Tablero.cpp
#include "Tablero.h"

Tablero::Tablero(void)
{
using std::cout;
casilla tab[3][3]; 
for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
{
    for (int c= 0;c<3;c++)
    {
        tab[f][c]=vacia;
    }
}
}

void Tablero::draw(void)
{
using std::cout;
using std::string;
for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
{
    for (int c= 0;c<3;c++)
    {
        string s;
        if (c!=2)
        {
            switch (tab[f][c])
            {
                case vacia: s=" "; break;
                case X: s="X"; break;
                case O: s="O";break;
            }
            cout << s.c_str() <<" | ";
        }
        else 
        {   
            switch (tab[f][c])
            {
                case vacia: s=" "; break;
                case X: s="X"; break;
                case O: s="O"; break;
            }
            cout << s.c_str() <<"\n";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where is `casilla ` defined?

Comment: You need to `#include` the header that defines `casilla` as well as probably the header that defines `Player` and `Tablero`. The compiler needs to see a declaration before you use it.

Comment: Is using a structure overkill for tic-tac-toe?  Most implementations use either a 2d array or a 9 slot array for the board.

Comment: The array type could be character:  'X', 'O' and ' ' (blank).

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at the first error.

```
//Jugador.h
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Jugador
{
public:
    string p_name;
//casilla is X,O or blankspace, done using enum in Tablero.h( it have to be in a cpp file)
    casilla c_o;
```

At this moment, the compiler does not know what a casilla is. Perhaps it is in some other file which has to be included, too, before any use of it:

```
//Jugador.h
#include <string>
#include <where-casilla-is-from>
using std::string;
...
```

Comment: When Jugador.h is excluded from the project i dont get any error, I can compile Jugador.h and the compiler knows what casilla is. The problem comes with Juego.h i guess.

Comment: Okay i fixed it now. The problem was the order of the includes in Juego.cpp. I just had to switch the order and include Tablero.h before Jugador.h because Jugador.h uses Tablero.h, as I said the book really doesnt explain this topic very well. Thanks for the quick responses!!